# Number won't go to two decimal places

Tags: c#

I'm making an interest application. I'm trying to get the amount of interest on the total amount to 2 decimal places. I've used `("N2")` all the way down through the code and it has worked except in one area which is in the label.

I use the label to display the total amount in the `Radiobutton()` area and it still displays the full figure `eg.14.8282423432` not to 2 decimal places. Any way to solve this? Thanks.

```
public void ShowRates()
    {
        Amount = ((Form1)Owner).Amount;
        WeekInterestRate = ((Form1)Owner).WeekInterestRate;
        TwoWeekInterestRate = ((Form1)Owner).TwoWeekInterestRate;
        MonthInterestRate = ((Form1)Owner).MonthInterestRate;
        ThreeMonthInterestRate = ((Form1)Owner).ThreeMonthInterestRate;

        WeekRateLabel.Text = WeekInterestRate.ToString("N2");
        TwoWeekLabel.Text = TwoWeekInterestRate.ToString("N2");
        MonthRateLabel.Text = MonthInterestRate.ToString("N2");
        TMonthRateLabel.Text = ThreeMonthInterestRate.ToString("N2");

        WeekPercent = (Amount * WeekInterestRate / 100);
        WeekInterestAmount = ((WeekPercent / 365) * 7);
        label6.Text = WeekInterestAmount.ToString("N2");

        TwoWeekInterestPercent = (Amount * TwoWeekInterestRate / 100);
        TwoWeekInterestAmount = ((TwoWeekInterestPercent / 365) * 14);
        label7.Text = TwoWeekInterestAmount.ToString("N2");

        MonthPercent = (Amount * MonthInterestRate / 100);
        MonthInterestAmount = ((MonthPercent / 365) * 30);
        label8.Text = MonthInterestAmount.ToString("N2");

        ThreeMonthPercent = (Amount * ThreeMonthInterestRate / 100);
        ThreeMonthInterestAmount = ((ThreeMonthPercent / 365) * 90);
        label9.Text = ThreeMonthInterestAmount.ToString("N2");
    }


    public void Back()
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Show(this);
        Hide();
    }
    public void RadioButtons()
    {

        if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            FinalAmount = (Amount + WeekInterestAmount);
            FinalAmount.ToString("N2");
            label10.Text = "Total Amount After 7 Days" + " " + "€" + FinalAmount;
            RateChosen = WeekInterestRate;
            InterestAmount = WeekInterestAmount;
            Days = WEEK;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
{
    FinalAmount = (Amount + WeekInterestAmount);
    label10.Text = "Total Amount After 7 Days" + " " + "€" + FinalAmount.ToString("N2");
    RateChosen = WeekInterestRate;
    InterestAmount = WeekInterestAmount;
    Days = WEEK;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
FinalAmount.ToString("N2");
```

Doesn't actually change FinalAmount at all.

```
string finald2 = FinalAmount.ToString("N2");
label10.Text = "Total Amount After 7 Days" + " " + "€" + finald2;
```

Try that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything with the `FinalAmount.toString("N2")` because it does not modify the original amount just the representation of it. Try this instead:

```
label10.Text = "Total Amount After 7 Days" + " " + "€" + FinalAmount.ToString("N2");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void RadioButtons()
{

    if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        FinalAmount = (Amount + WeekInterestAmount);
        label10.Text = "Total Amount After 7 Days" + " " + "€" + FinalAmount.ToString("N2");
        RateChosen = WeekInterestRate;
        InterestAmount = WeekInterestAmount;
        Days = WEEK;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line does nothing:

```
FinalAmount.ToString("N2");
```

Well, actually it does something. It formats the value as a string, but then the result is discarded.

Use that code in the line where you put it in the label:

```
label10.Text = "Total Amount After 7 Days" + " " + "€" + FinalAmount.ToString("N2");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
label10.Text = string.Format("Total Amount After 7 Days {0:C}", FinalAmount);
```

This will automatically format `FinalAmount` as currency with the currency symbol and 2 decimal places. Like `N2` it uses the `CurrentCulture` to determine the thousands separator, the currency symbol, and the decimal separator.

Alternatively you can continue hardcoding the currency symbol and change it to:

```
label10.Text = string.Format("Total Amount After 7 Days €{0:N2}", FinalAmount);
```